# Save JavaRDD to HDFS from Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to save my Spark JavaRDD to HDFS. The process run successfully but I do not see file saved in HDFS. Below is my code. I am running it locally. (running main() method directly from IntelliJ.)

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        String file = "/Path/to/file/abc.csv";

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

       JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(file);


        JavaRDD<String > filteredLines = lines.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(String s) throws Exception {
                return s.contains("Hollywood");
            }
        });

        filteredLines.coalesce(1).saveAsObjectFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/input");

        sc.close();
    }
```

I am running this code on Spark 2.0 and Hadoop 2.7.2. In my hadoop core-site.xml is configured as localhost:9000. I am starting my HDFS pseudo distributed cluster as mentioned in the hadoop documentation.

What am I missing here?

Comment: so you are running this code on the same machine which has Hadoop setup ?  if not try with hostname once.

Comment: Yes. Running code from same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to resolve this. There were 2 issues

1) I am using Hadoop-2.7.2 and my java version was jdk1.8. It seems JDK1.8 is only supported for Hadoop2.0 onward. For Hadoop-2.7 I need JDK1.7. I changed my java version to 1.7

2) The Hadoop directory was missing permission. Executing

chmod -R 755 /hadoop/directory

provided necessary permission.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried with `saveAsSequenceFile`?

just look at this

[https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/SequenceFileRDDFunctions.html](http://link%201)

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Tried with saveAsSequenceFile as well as saveAsObjectFile. None of them worked

Comment: @user7005835, once loook at this i hope you definitely find a solution  https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/java/BasicSaveSequenceFile.java

Comment: Thank you for the link css2607. In my case I don't want to use JavaPairRDD and I don't think saveAsHadoopFile method is there for JavaRDD.